# Comparing two table columns to see what one table is missing

Tags: sql

So currently I have two tables,

```
Servers              Admins
-------             --------
ServerID             AdminID
ServerName           AdminFirstName
Server location      AdminFirstName 
AdminID
```

What I am currently trying to do is go through the `AdminID` column in the `Servers` table and compare it to the `AdminID` column in the `Admins` table.
The comparison I'm trying to make is "What admins have not been assigned to a server yet?", and "What servers do not have an admin assigned to them yet?"

I have tried the following (to attempt the first question):

```
SELECT CONCAT(AdminLastName,',',AdminFirstName)
FROM Admins
WHERE AdminID NOT IN(SELECT AdminID FROM Servers)
```

The query is returning 0 results, when it should be returning a few.
Since both questions can be answered with virtually the same logic, I just need a push in the right direction as to why this is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your query looks correct at first glance :O

Comment: @Kritner that's what I thought too. But it's not returning any results!

Comment: Could there be a problem with trailing spaces?

Comment: Without data, we can't say because that does look correct.  Are you sure that this query is supposed to have results and not the other query that you mentioned.

You could try to select * instead of select concat to see if concat is behaving weird.  what dbms is this on?

Comment: trailing spaces (at least to sql server) are disregarded, but I would imagine OPs adminId column would be an integer (though that is an assumption)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't believe so, I've actually checked that with no luck

Comment: @drneel Tried it without the CONCAT with no luck, I have verified the data and do see that their are `AdminID`s in the `Admins` table that are not in the `Servers` table

Comment: @OysterMaker is there a foreign key relationship between the two?  Or are you allowed to have adminIds in server that don't exist in admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks correct to me, but I tend to try to avoid `NOT IN` when possible, as I usually get better performance out of a query written like:

```
select adminId, adminfirstname, adminlastname
from admins a
left join servers s on a.adminId = s.adminId
where s.adminId is null
```

the above is the same idea, just using a join and showing only the results that didn't successfully join.

the other one could be written as:

```
select serverId, serverName, [server location]
from servers
where adminId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be correct.

It can be due to several things :

- All admins are actually assigned to a server
- You dont execute query on the right database...
- There is a problem with ID column's contents : if it's not INTEGER it can contain spaces or other non-desired characters in one of the two tables, and it does not match for the database system. Try to TRIM() the Id's for example
- Depending on your database system, it can be better to write table names explicitly since you have the same field name in multiple tables

For example :

```
SELECT CONCAT(AdminLastName,',',AdminFirstName)
FROM Admins
WHERE TRIM(Admins.AdminID) NOT IN(SELECT TRIM(Servers.AdminID) FROM Servers)
```